# Javascript for summing primes crashing

Tags: javascript, recursion, for-loop, while-loop, primes

I have the following exercise code where I'm trying to calculate the sum of all the primes from 1-10 which is crashing due to recursion.
I'm having trouble with my for and while loops as the code doesn't seem to be cycling through my **var i**, and is getting stuck on the initial assignment of **i = 3**.
I'm not looking for the correct answer or the most efficient answer yet but I am looking for someone to help me understand what's wrong.
Here's the code:

```
var array = [2];
var total = 0; 
var j = 0;
function isPrime(i, j) {
if ( i%array[j] === 0 ) {
        console.log("i was " + i + " and j was " + j);
        console.log(i + " is not a prime");
        j = array.length;
    }
    else if ((j + 1) === array.length) {
        console.log(i + " is a prime");
        total += i;
        console.log("total so far is " + total);
        array.push(i);
        console.log(array);
        j = array.length;
        console.log(j);
    }
    else {
        j++;
        isPrime(i,j);
    }
}

for(var i = 3; i <=10; i++) {
   while(j < array.length) {
       console.log("i is " + i + " and j is " +j);
       isPrime(i, j);
   }
}

console.log(total);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var j = 0;
function isPrime(i, j) { …
```

means that you have two distinct `j` variables: One outside the function, and one inside that shadows the other. From inside you never will be able to assign or read the outer variable. Therefore, the outer `j` stays `0` forever and `while (j < array.length)` will loop infinitely.

Comment: By shadow do you mean that the j in the function is a copy of the j initially introduced and assigned a 0, so I will have a **j=0** outside of the function that remains assigned to 0 and a **j=0** inside the function? Or is the j inside the function automatically assigned a 0 since I did not specify an assignment? Either way, I thought that since I assigned the initial j outside the function, then that j is public and accessible by any part of the code, is it not?

Comment: No, "shadow" means that you can't see the outer variable from inside the function since the inner one is bound stronger. There is no hidden initialisation, the inner `j` is just what you passed as a parameter (and may it be the value of the outer j) or `undefined`.